# Ruby on Rails test fails or succeeds depending on how the test suite is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, railstutorial.org

I'm working my way through the Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial (4th Edition) and I've come across a problem with some tests I'm trying to run - specifically the exercise in section 11.2.3. All of my tests are green up to this point.

I test the new piece of code:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rails test:mailers
Started with run options --seed 59483

  1/1: [======================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.33304s
1 tests, 9 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Everything is groovy.

I attempt to run the full test suite:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 11914
Started with run options --seed 56533

ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 1.2505091589991935]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1.25s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__2910351700178259135_47130470135880'
            app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
            test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

  48/48: [========================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.71036s
48 tests, 206 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Bugger. Testing which I won't bother reproducing here confirms that it's definitely the same piece of code that's failing in one place and working in the other.

However, if instead of calling `rails test` I call `rails test:run`, then this happens:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rails test:run
Started with run options --seed 50303

  48/48: [========================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.72194s
48 tests, 215 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

And similarly, if I use `rake test` or `rake test:run`, then everything is fine.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rake test
(in /vagrant/sample_app)
Started with run options --seed 9429

  48/48: [========================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.70475s
48 tests, 215 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rake test:run
(in /vagrant/sample_app)
Started with run options --seed 50280

  48/48: [========================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.73529s
48 tests, 215 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? And ideally how to make just a `rails test` call work again?

**EDIT**

Started `rails test` with the same seed used by `rails test:run` to show that it's not anything to do with test ordering.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rails test:run 
Started with run options --seed 326

  48/48: [=======================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.66690s
48 tests, 215 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
vagrant@ubuntu-18:/vagrant/sample_app/test$ rails test --seed 326
Running via Spring preloader in process 28117
Started with run options --seed 326

ERROR["test_account_activation", UserMailerTest, 1.605607868055813]
 test_account_activation#UserMailerTest (1.61s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__2910351700178259135_47130458820540'
            app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'
            test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

  48/48: [=======================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.64637s
48 tests, 206 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

`rake TESTOPTS="--seed=326"` also succeeds.

**EDIT 2**

Test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account Activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ['noreply@example.com'], mail.from
    assert_match user.name, mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token, mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI.escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end


end
```

Method Tested:
(where the line beginning mail to: is user_mailer.rb:10)

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Account Activation"
  end

end
```

Fixture:

```
michael:
    name: Michael Example
    email: michael@example.com
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
    admin: true
    activated: true
    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

Template:

```
<h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>, </p>
<p>Welcome to the Sample App! Please click on the link belowe to activate your account.</p>

<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Comment: You would need to post the Test and at a minimum the code in "app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:10:in `account_activation'" for us to assist chances are it is just an issue with isolation (or lack thereof) for this test. Also as an aside 9 assertions in 1 test seems excessive (as does an average of ~4.5 assertions per test)

Comment: @engineersmnky You have to blame that on Hartl though. The tests have been garbage since he switched to minitest.

Comment: @max to be honest I never finished his original tutorial, way back when, and haven't even looked at anything recent. I learned a lot more from why's pragmatic guide (which is extremely out of date now) because learning rails is easy if you understand ruby but learning ruby is hard if you understand rails.

Comment: You can use the seed option `rails test --seed 56533` to run the tests in a predetermined order. This can help troubleshoot issues with isolation. I doubt there is any actual difference with the different commands. `rails test:run` is just defined as `task run: %w[test]`. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7e52e3b1c004eb22521c844b6adf69a2689cc1da/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake#L26

Comment: @engineersmnky Edited; let me know if there's any other information you need.

Comment: I notice there's a spring call mentioned. You could try preceeding it with `spring stop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @AJFaraday for pointing out in the comments that the Spring preloader was running.

I called `spring stop`, and the problem resolved itself.

Spring seems to have turned itself back on again, but `rails test` is now giving the same test results as the other three methods.

Comment: Disable spring permanently with `export DISABLE_SPRING=1` in your shell config. As you've now seen firsthand, spring saves you seconds so you can waste days. I don't know any professional developer who works with spring enabled.